# When using BibLaTex, encountered LaTeX Warning: Citation `foo' on page N undefined on input line XX

Tags: biblatex

This question has been asked in Tex.S.E. before; an answer that seems to have solved the problem for `BibTex` users has been given:  [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63852/question-mark-instead-of-citation-number). I use `Biber` and have followed every step in Paul Stanley's answer as close as possible but still encounter the same error: `LaTeX Warning: Citation 'foo' on page N undefined on input line XX. LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line YY.`

A `.bcf` file and a `.pdf` file are generated but in the pdf I just see the citation key in bold instead of the actual citation.

I use MikTex 2.9 + TexMaker in Windows 10. I have BibLaTex 3.3 and Biber 2.4, these are compatible with each other per [Biber documentation](ftp://ftp.fau.de/ctan/biblio/biber/documentation/biber.pdf)

MWE (stolen from [Can't create a bibliography using biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/300204/cant-create-a-bibliography-using-biblatex/300223)):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{cmap}                   
\usepackage{mathtext}           
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}       
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\frenchspacing
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8,maxcitenames=2,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{biblio.bib}

@article{quiroga2012concept,
  title={Concept cells: the building blocks of declarative memory functions},
  author={Quiroga, Rodrigo Quian},
  journal={Nature Reviews Neuroscience},
  volume={13},
  number={8},
  pages={587--597},
  year={2012},
  publisher={Nature Publishing Group}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\author{John Doe}
\section{section name}
\noindent Russian text \cite{quiroga2012concept}.\par

\end{document}
```

I am sure I am using Biber in compilation instead of BibTex, as I have `pdflatex %.tex | biber % | pdflatex %.tex | pdflatex %.tex` specified in TexMaker like user John Crawford shows in [Setting up TexMaker on Ubuntu "biblatex.sty not found."](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102817/setting-up-texmaker-on-ubuntu-biblatex-sty-not-found)

Which part of Paul Stanley's answer applies to `Biber`? He mentioned `.blg` and `.bst` but it seems `Biber` doesn't generate these files.

Thanks! Any help is greatly appreciated.

Update with new error message:
I followed Torbjørn T's suggestion [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154751/biblatex-with-biber-configuring-my-editor-to-avoid-undefined-citations/154788#154788) and this time:

```
INFO - This is Biber 2.3 INFO - Logfile is 'foo.blg'
ERROR - Cannot find control file 'foo.bcf'! - did you pass the "backend=biber" option to BibLaTeX?
```

But the `backend=biber` option is right there in the `\usepackage{biblatex}`.

Update with no error message but no citation:

Followed Bernard's suggestion to change the BibTex configuration in TexMaker, then update MikTek. Now I have no error message - not even "citation foo undefined", but the citation still only shows the citation key. However `\printbibliography` prints all references.

Update:
I still don't have citations but at least now the TeX document compiles and all the references in my `.bib` show up in the resulted `.pdf`.

Comment: Just `%` will do, the extensions are not necessary.

Comment: Bernard - I removed the extensions and the error persists.

Comment: So you have `pdflatex %.tex | biber % | pdflatex %.tex | pdflatex %.tex | evince %.pdf`? What if you run biber from a terminal?

Comment: Oh, you wont have `evince` on Windows, so you can remove `| evince %.pdf`. Don't know what viewer you have set up, but F7 is the shortcut for View PDF I believe. That shouldn't affect the warning you're seeing though.

Comment: @Torbjørn T.: The .tex extension following biber doesn't seem to matter; having it produces the same error as not having it. I am in Windows 10. Is there an alternative way to run biber in Windows? Also I just removed `evince %.pdf` from TexMaker configuration and you were right - the error is still there.

Comment: Haven't used Windows in a long time. Do you have MikTeX (proTeX) or TeX Live installed? Perhaps [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154788) is useful.

Comment: @Torbjørn T: Did the configuration and am met with new error.

Comment: Well at least `biber` runs, so that is good. I don't know why it doesn't find the `.bcf` file though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect Texmaker is configured to use a `build` subdirectory for output files. If it is indeed the case, the line for `(Bib)latex` should be

`C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\/miktex/bin/x64/biber.exe" build\%`

(I suppose  MiKTeX is installed in the default place).

Answer (score 1):

Answer for documentation purpose:

1. One must explicitly make sure `Biber`and `BibLaTeX` versions are compatible with each other. That the two packages came in the same `MikTeX` distribution doesn't necessary mean that they will work together.
2. `Texmaker` needs to be set up correctly: [Setting up TexMaker on Ubuntu "biblatex.sty not found."](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102817/setting-up-texmaker-on-ubuntu-biblatex-sty-not-found), plus Bernard's answer if Texmaker's "Use a build subdirectory for output files" option is enabled.